# Detect when an image touch a building

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

How can I solve that I put an **image** on a certain coordinate and send message to console if the image touch any **building**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I think you can achieve this as follows:

1. Use a `Marker` to add the image to a location (see https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/ )
2. Given the HTML element for the marker, `el`, use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to find the pixel positions of it, relative to the viewport.
3. Do some maths to find those positions relative to the map.
4. Call `map.queryRenderedFeatures()` with those positions, to detect if there is any building within the area of the marker image.